# Unable to activate the publishing feature on a SharePoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm having trouble with a site collection in a MOSS2007 farm. I'm trying to enable the Publishing feature at the site collection level. When I try to activate the Feature from Site Settings -> site Collection features, I get one of those incredibly helpful SharePoint error messages.

```
Error. Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
```

So I thought I'd try with stsadm, and I ran this

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name Publishing -url http://server/site
```

I got the more helpful error message

```
Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to create the 'Pages' library.
OriginalException: The feature failed to activate because a list at 'Pages' already
exists in this site.  Delete or rename the list and try activating the feature
again.
```

Now that's more like it! I checked, and sure enough there was a Pages library. I deleted it. I ran stsadm again fully expecting it to work this time. No dice. I'm getting the same error, but now there's no 'Pages' document library. I emptied the recycle bin. Same error. I'm stumped.

Per the two suggestions below, I made sure that the site collection recylcle bin was also emptied and that there were no 'Images' or 'Documents' libraries hanging around. I still can't activate the feature.

Comment: Brian, Did you empty both recycle bins?

Answer (score 2):

Try running a utility like [Sharepoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) on your site. Maybe it will see a list called Pages that for some reason you aren't seeing through the web interface.

Comment: Nope, no other 'Pages' list or library in SharePoint Manager. Neat tool though. thanks for th link.

Answer (score 0):

The publishing features creates three libraries (among other things)

1. Pages
2. Images
3. Documents

You might need to delete more than just the Pages library.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes list, web, or page already exist while you are running provisioning code
 you can use sharepoint designer to pin point that object and delete it from there

Cheers